# Automation framework to run both UI and mobile automation

Tags: ui-automation, browser-automation, cucumber-serenity, serenity-spring

Our use case involves automating both Web and mobile. Certain actions are carried out on Web post which the data flows to mobile device. Then certain actions need to be carried out on mobile device.

Is there an automation framework which can do both Web and mobile automation as a single flow.
I tried using Serenity with Selenium and Appium. But through the properties file, either Chrome browser or Android emulator can be launched at a single point of time.

**Sample cucumber feature file usecase**

```
Given user enters "admin" and password "admin" and clicks on login button
When user enter "Item1" as "Data1"
And user clicks submit button
Then verify success message on UI. 
And verify "Data1" saved in Db. 
When user launches mobile device
And user enters "admin" and password "admin" and clicks login button
Then verify "Data1" is displayed on mobile device.
When user clicks on "Item2" on mobile device
Then verify "Data1" is updated on mobile device
And verify "Data1" is updated on the Web.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that the actions in the browser actually perform REST calls to the backend, in this case I would suggest you directly call the backend endpoints instead of trying to do it in the browser and mobile application at the same time. A great framework that you can use to execute backend calls and Appium tests at the same time is [Carina](https://github.com/zebrunner/carina)

Comment: I am not looking for backend calls but rather running Browser testing and Mobile app testing as a single test case

Comment: Yes, I see you have edited your question but the answer is still legit - Carina supports backend, web and mobile automation